# jquery get href in children()

Tags: jquery

```
  alert($(this).children().next().html());
```

returns

```
  <a href="thelink.php?id=XXXX">click me...</a>
```

How do I change above statement to grab only the href?

Have tried attr('href') but can't get it to work.

(Yes, jq-noob and no time.)

//edit - code added:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="date">
    <h2>27</h2>
    <h3>dec</h3>
  </div>
  <h2><a href="/wpb/index.php?id=4192#4199">the title..</a></h2>
  <p>the description...</p>
</div>

jq invoked by:
$("#threecol .row").click(function() {  
  alert($(this).children().next().href);
});
```

regards,

Comment: What exactly do you get when you try $(this).children().next().attr('href') ?

Comment: `attr('href')` is correct. But how you select the elements looks strange. Could you please post the corresponding HTML and tell us which element you want to get? `.children().next()` basically selects every child except the first one.

Comment: These answers are disappointingly wrong.

Comment: attr("href") is the right thing to do. it's probably your selector that is wrong. Post some more code and HTML snippet so that we can see the problem

Comment: If you post the relevant HTML, we can help you better. More information => better answers.

Comment: `.children().next()` doesn't make any sense.  What are you trying to select?

Comment: Side note: Don't use `<h*>` elements for styling. Use CSS. The heading elements have a distinct semantic meaning.

Comment: @Felix: He's using the semantic meaning.

Comment: @SLaks: I don't know.... it looks strange to me. Headings but no content? Different importance of the day and the month? The day is at the same level as the following link?

Comment: @Felix: I didn't notice those; I was referring to the `<h2>` with the link.  You're right.

Comment: @SLaks , @Felix , headers are used for day/month to minimize code (no span/div). What would you suggest as a better option?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Find the attribute value using .attr('href').

EDIT: The first anchor within a H2:

```
alert($(this).find('h2 a:first').attr('href'));
```

You could also reference it via a class if you prefer and use the class in your anchor.

```
alert($(this).find('.myLink').attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 11):

`$(this).children().next()` is returning an element that has an `<a>` inside of it.
To get that `<a>`'s `href`, you need to select it, then call `.attr('href')`.

You want to write something like

```
alert($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'));
```

In your case, you may want to write `.find('h2 a')`.

Comment: yes, it works, thanks! For knowledge, I'd like to know how to traverse down to it however. (See added code).

Comment: @user: `$(this).children('h2').children('a')`

Answer (score -4):

You can try this:

Edited:
`alert($(this).find("a").attr("href"));`

Comment: `html()` returns a string, you cannot call `attr()` on it.